# How do I get the data from a composable on mount?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs3, fetch-api

I'm working on an interview question I had last week which asks for a way to display a list of users based on data fetched from an API. In the problem, it said you had to get the data when the component mounted. I wanted to try and practice composables, so I made one that did the fetching for me. The issue is, I can't seem to access the data when mounting, leading to me getting this error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'users')."

I've been able to solve the error by just conditionally rendering the child component, which you will see in the code I will post below. Still, I want to know how to make sure it is loaded when the component mounts, rather than conditionally rendering the component.

```js
//dummyfetcher.js

/* This is the composable that I am using to fetch the data */

import { ref, unref, watchEffect, onMounted } from 'vue'

export function useFetch(urlStem, pageNum) {
  const data = ref(null)
  const error = ref(null)

  function doFetch() {
    // reset state before fetching..
    data.value = null
    error.value = null
    // unref() unwraps potential refs
    fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/${unref(urlStem)}?skip=${unref(pageNum)*10}&limit=10`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => (data.value = json))
      .catch((err) => (error.value = err))
  }

  watchEffect(doFetch)
  onMounted(() => {
  /* Vue's documentation suggested you can access the lifecycle methods of the component, but I get that this doesn't work because the component itself isn't calling the composable until after the component has been mounted */
    doFetch()
  })

  return { data, error }
}
```

The above code is my composable that does the fetching.

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<script setup>
import { ref, watch, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useFetch } from './composables/dummyfetcher.js';
import Users from './components/Users.vue';

const urlStem = ref("users"); //We start with users, but leave this as a ref so that we can decide on what data to show
const pageList = ['products', 'carts', 'users', 'posts', 'comments', 'quotes', 'todos']
const currentPage = ref(0)
const { data, error } = useFetch(urlStem, currentPage);
const lastPage = ref(0)

onMounted(() => {
  // I tried this solution, but
  return data;
})
watch(data, (newData) => {
  if (newData) {
    lastPage.value = Math.floor(newData.total / 10) - (newData.total % 10 === 0 ? 1 : 0)
  }
})

const changePage = (e, page) => {
  urlStem.value = page;
  currentPage.value = 0
}

</script>

<template>
  <button v-for="(page, index) in pageList" :key="index" @click="event => changePage(event, page)">{{ page }}</button>
  <button @click="currentPage = 0" :disabled="currentPage === 0" id="first">First page</button>
  <button @click="currentPage--" :disabled="currentPage === 0" id="prev">Previous Page</button>
  <button @click="currentPage++" :disabled="currentPage === lastPage" id="next">Next Page</button>
  <button @click="currentPage = lastPage" :disabled="currentPage === lastPage" id="last">Last Page</button>
  <!-- In this div, I'm replacing the onMounted with a conditional render. This works, but I want to know how to do it using onMounted instead -->
  <div v-if="data">
    <Users :data="data[urlStem]" />
  </div>
</template>
```

This above is my App.vue file. This is with conditional rendering rather than onMounted.

```html
<!-- Users.vue -->
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue';

defineProps(['data'])

</script>

<template v-if="">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    First Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    Last Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    Age
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="(user, index) in data" :key="index">
                <td>
                    {{ user.id }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ user.firstName }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ user.lastName }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ user.age }}
                </td>
            </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

This code above is the final file, which is Users.vue. In it, I'm getting the data from the parent component which was received from the composable and then rendering it.

So all of this is to say, is there a way to do this in onMounted instead of using conditional rendering? Also, to do this, would I have to move the fetch into my file instead of using a composable or could I still use the composable?

Comment: Did you try to make onMounted asynchronous instead?